# Angular 2 router create wrong link

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular-cli, angular-routing

I have somthing like this in routing

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component : HomeComponent,
        children: []
    },
    {
        path: 'login',
        children: [
            {
                path: '',
                component: LoginComponent
            },
            {
                path: 'with-email',
                component: LoginWithEmailComponent
            },
            {
                path: 'forgot-password',
                component: LoginForgotPasswordComponent
            }
        ]
    }   
];
```

It works ok, until i am on with-email page, and do somthing like this

```
  <span><a routerLink="forgot-password"><i class="p1-icon-arrow"></i>Forgot password?</a></span>
```

it does not back me to login and forgot-password, it create a link like this

**/login/with-email/forgot-password**

Why it does not back me to **login/forgot-passwprd**

Comment: If you have a route with an empty path (`''`) without child routes, add `pathMatch: 'full'` (in both cases above). In email page (if it is `LoginWithEmailComponent`) then it should be `routerLink="../forgot-password"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In email page (if it is LoginWithEmailComponent) then it should be

```
routerLink="../forgot-password"
```